# logger + how to change the logger title instead user root

Tags: linux, logs, logger

I want to use the log - /var/log/message for my logs
my application name is - whatsapp_man

for example I send the following warning to the log

```
[root@worker01 ~]# logger "please noitce you are before attack"
[root@worker01 ~]# tail -1 /var/log/messages
Mar  4 13:28:05 worker01 root: please notice you are before attack
[root@worker01 ~]#
```

but how to use the logger in order to get whatsapp_man instead of root

as the fowling expected results

```
[root@worker01 ~]# logger [....] "please notice you are before attack"
[root@worker01 ~]# tail -1 /var/log/messages
Mar  4 13:28:05 worker01  whatsapp_man: please notice you are before attack
[root@worker01 ~]#
```

Comment: its workers , can I ask another question please , let say we want to use the logger on some other log file as /var/log/server.log , is it possible to use loggger to write logs to server.log?

Comment: any please wrote answer to the first question and I will vote for you

Comment: for your commented-question, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67708/logger-command-how-to-store-logs-in-given-file and/or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434459/logger-f-command-killed-opening-var-log-messages-in-tail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix you're looking for is provided by the [`-t` option of logger](https://linux.die.net/man/1/logger):

```
logger -t whatsapp_man "..."
```